# What does "dot square bracket .[]" notation mean in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, pip

What does the following `.[text]` (dot square bracket) syntax means in Makefile?

[Makefile](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.4/Makefile#L6)

```
install:
    pip install -e .[test]

test:
    py.test
```

According to [`pip install -e <path/url>`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-e), `.[test]` is expected to be a path or urls.

Comment: Stop me if I am asking the wrong question here. (i.e. it has nothing related to Makefile)

Answer (score 2):

`.[test]` is actually a path. Let me explain:

- `.` is simply current directory, so it installs packages included in `install_requires` from [setup.py](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.4/setup.py) which is located in current directory.
- `[test]` causes the installation of extra packages listed in `test_requires` from previously mentioned [setup.py](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.4/setup.py). [Here](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) you can read more about extras.